# QueryFilter() return array of structure in coldfusion2016. But it's should return query

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, coldfusion-2018

Here I'm working with **QueryFilter()** function. I've go through this function usage & return type. **The adobe docs said it's return query**. But sample code return **array of structure in coldfusion2016**.  I've tried the same code in **cf2018 but it's return the query** only.

So I've tried with same code **trycf.com**. While **I choose cf2016 in trycf there also return type in query** only. But I don't know why my cf2016 return array of structure. My sample code.

```
<cfscript>

    news = queryNew("id,type,title", "integer,varchar,varchar");
    queryAddRow(news,[{
        id: 1,
        type: "book",
        title: "Cloud Atlas"
    },{
        id: 2,
        type: "book",
        title: "Lord of The Rings"
    },{
        id: 3,
        type: "film",
        title: "Men in Black"
    }]);


    books = QueryFilter(news,function(_news) {
        return _news.type is 'book';
    });
    writeDump(books);

</cfscript>
```

**CF2016 Output in my local :**

[image]

**CF2018 Output :**

[image]

Could you please any one know the root causes of this issue ?

Comment: Do you have the latest updates for ColdFusion 2016 installed?

Comment: I've update up to update10. Is that fixed any specific updates ? @RRK

Comment: It's resolved in update11. I got a return type as query now. Thank you all & @RRK

Comment: You should write that up as the answer. It might help the next person with this issue.

Comment: @JamesAMohler . Sure I will write it in answer part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the **queryFilter()** should return the Filtered query.We have the issue that return type as array of structure in before update11 in cf2016. So once I've update my cf2016 from **update10 to update11.** It's get resolved. Now my queryFilter() function return the query only.

So **update11 resolved this problem in cf2016**. Thank you.